# How can I add spark as maven depenency?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I try to import

`import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaDoubleRDD;`

but I can't find it on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com), how can I add this dependency in pom.xml ? Currently I have

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

but this is obviously not enough.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: It's on mavenrepository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/2.1.0

Comment: Maybe refresh your project? I know in intelliJ there's an option to reload mvn deps, not sure about other IDE's. As @MatthiasFax said, it's on mvnrepository and your pom.xml seems ok

Comment: Remember there is a confusing naming convention in Spark jars (due scala/sbt) where the version of scala used is encoded in the artifactId too - this can be strange at first (especially as 2.10 looks a bit like 2.1.0!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it's on there, you can find it from:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10

I'm using `sbt` and works fine with:

> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1" % "provided"

I believe the maven equivalent config with version `2.10` is just enough.

Comment: SBT might not be the first choice for a Java application. Moreover, your example shows the wrong Scala build (2.11) and Spark version (2.0.1).

Comment: Thanks for response :-). I'm linking to the version specified in the question, but the version in sbt config is what I'm using, it's not the same.